# Convert PyTorch to CoreML

Tags: python, pytorch, coremltools

I have this model: https://github.com/williamyang1991/DualStyleGAN and try to convert it to CoreML. So far I [create copy](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_4_FXCfWLPMbJvIxR5s2QlSwTHOvLWt7#scrollTo=ph3R7lbl_arQ) of original Colab notebook and append at the end two blocks:

```
!pip install coremltools
import coremltools as ct
```

and

```
#@title Convert inverted image.
inverted_latent = torch.Tensor(result_latents[0][4]).cuda().unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(1)

with torch.no_grad():
    net.eval()

    [sampled_src, sampled_dst] = net(inverted_latent, input_is_latent=True)[0]

    traced_model = torch.jit.trace(net, inverted_latent)
    mlmodel = ct.convert(traced_model, inputs=[ct.ImageType(name="input", shape=inverted_latent.shape,bias=[-1,-1,-1],scale=2.0/255.0)])
    mlmodel.save("modelsaved.mlmodel")
```

To run it, you should put any image with face to /content and in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py
replace round method at 545, 546 lines with np.round

But then it fails at

> mlmodel = ct.convert(...

with:

> RuntimeError: PyTorch convert function for op 'pythonop' not implemented.

I suggest that there the way to rewrite this module with methods that could be convert, am I right? But I can't to figure out how to find the source of this module.

So my question is:
If I think in a right way, how I can find the source of module?
And if I wrong, please advise me the right way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

The code starts by loading the model into PyTorch.
The code then converts the model into CoreML format and saves it to a .mlmodel file.The code below will take the existing PyTorch model and convert it into a CoreML model with input and output features.
The outputs are saved in the file example.mlmodel which can be opened in Xcode or any other development environment that supports CoreML models.

```
 import torch
 import coremltools


  model = torch.load('MyPyTorchModel.pt')


 coreml_model = coremltools.converters.pytorch.from_pytorch(model,
                                                           input_features= 
 ['input'],
                                                           output_features= 
 ['output'])


 coreml_model.save('MyCoreMLModel.mlmodel')
```